# python one liner for assignment in loop

Tags: python, one-liner

In two lines I can do something like:

```
for object in object_list:
    object.param = 10
```

Is there any way to do this in one line?

something like:

```
(object.param = 10) for object in object_list
```

Comment: You can do `for o in object_list: o.param = 10` on one line if you want.  It's just generally considered bad style.

Comment: The `for` loop is the idiomatic way to do this in Python.

Answer (score -1):

This is the typical use case for `setattr` and its corresponding "dunder" (double-underscore function) `__setattr__`. You can use these in any comprehension (list, dictionary or set) or any generator comprehension.

```
[setattr(obj,'attr',value)for obj in object_list]
```

```
[obj.__setattr__('attr',value)for obj in object_list]
```

This could also be achieved via combinations of `map` and `lambda` to avoid the comprehension aspect, though to execute these you would have to iterate through the map. In the example below I've used `[*map()]` for this for brevity, but `list(map)` is a slightly longer approach which achieves essentially the same thing.

`[*map(lambda obj:setattr(obj,'param',value),object_list)]`

`[*map(lambda obj:obj.__setattr__('attr',value),object_list)]`

Comment: No, this is not the typical use-case for `setattr`.

Comment: @chepner right, `setattr()` is just the workaround for not being able to use walrus as in my attempted solution.

Comment: In general you should not use a dunder method directly when you can use the corresponding function. The dunder method is intended for classes to define in order to customize the behavior of the function.

Comment: The dunder method is included for demonstration and learning purposes for the OP.

Comment: That is, `setattr` is not intended to be used just so you can abuse the list comprehension for iteration purposes. You don't want a list full of `None` values created by `setattr`.

Comment: The `map` versions are particularly grotesque. It's the list you don't want; it doesn't matter if you use an unpacked `map` or a list comprehension to produce it.

Comment: In this case the expression is intended to be on a line itself.